How can I typeset \sim-like arrow?
How can I create a \sim-like arrow like this:

I can't seem to find it anywhere!

Welcome. // Please add a short code example, which compiles AND shows the context you want to use it. Use an other arrow as placeholder. This will result in more and better answers. Thank you

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathllap
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % for \rightlsquigarrow
\usepackage{scalerel} % for \scalerel

\newcommand{\approxrightarrow}{
  \mathrel{
    \scalerel*{
      \lower.1em\hbox{$\rightlsquigarrow$}
      \mathllap{\lower-.15em\hbox{$\rightlsquigarrow$}}}
      {\approx}
    }}

\begin{document}

$x\approxrightarrow x$

\end{document}


